# jQuery functions only work inside .ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still new to jQuery and I'm wondering how come the jQuery functions called inside .ready() work just fine but not outside?

For example, this would work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#field1').click(function() {
        $('#result').load('/random_post #post');
    });
});
```

But this won't:

```
$('#field1').click(function() {
    $('#result').load('/random_post #post');
});
```

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery explains why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How and if it works will depend on the order of which scripts and elements are laid out in your HTML, and it might also be affected by parameters outside your control (e.g. how the browser is programmed to behave).

I 'd hazard a guess that this script appears in your page *before* the element with `id="field1"` that gets a click handler added; this causes the script to run and find no such element in the document tree (yet). The element gets added after the script runs, which is why jQuery finds it just fine after the whole document has loaded.

If you move this script at the very end of your page it should work (although of course the correct solution is to use the document ready event, as in your first snippet).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access the DOM until the document is fully parsed and the DOM constructed. That includes modifying any elements  – such as `#field1` and `#result`.

Since `$(document).ready(..)` is long and may be hard to remember, you can also use the short form `$(onReadyFunction)`, i.e.

```
$(function() {
    $('#field1').click(function() {
        $('#result').load('/random_post #post');
    });
});
```

By the way, jQuery does no magic here: It just registers your function to be called when `DOMContentLoaded` (or equivalent) event is triggered by the parsing and construction of the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

The ready function is executed when the dom tree has been created. You get an error in your second piece of code because the dom tree element with id filed1 has not been created yet, i.e. the page hasn't loaded yet.